# Formula for graph average clustering coefficient

Tags: graph

A graph contains N nodes in a ring. Each node is connected to 4 other nodes on positions n-2, n-1, n+1, n+2, if n is the position of each node.

[image]

I found the formula to calculate each node's clustering coefficient:

[image]

where

- Nv is the number of links between neighbors of node v,
- Kv is the number of neighbors of node v

Additionally, the graph should include N/2 random links:

[image]

This graph's average clustering coefficient equals 0.47777777777777786.

I have tried to understand by calculating using NetworkX library and after 100000 runs, the average values of the average clustering coefficients were the following:

- 0.6836288481928767 for N=8
- 0.4970500101826404 for N=12
- 0.4003510099434803 for N=24

However, I do not know how this can be calculated using formula.

How is the above-stated formula changed when N/2 random links are added to the graph?

The code:

```
import networkx as nx 
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout
import random

def getClusteringCoefficient(N, show_graph = False):

    G = nx.Graph()

    def next(node_from, diff):
        node_from = (node_from+diff)%N
        if(node_from==0):
            node_from = N
        return node_from

    for node_from in range(1, N+1):
        node_to_1 = next(node_from, 1)
        node_to_2 = next(node_from, 2)
        G.add_weighted_edges_from([(node_from, node_to_1, 1)])
        G.add_weighted_edges_from([(node_from, node_to_2, 1)])
    
    count=0
    random_connections = int(N/2)
    while(True):
        node_from = random.randint(1,N)
        not_neighbors = list(nx.non_neighbors(G,node_from))
        if(len(not_neighbors)==0):
            continue
        node_to_pos = random.randint(0,len(not_neighbors)-1)
        node_to = not_neighbors[node_to_pos]
        G.add_weighted_edges_from([(node_from, node_to, 1)])
        count=count+1
        if(count==random_connections):
            break;
        
    if(show_graph):
        pos=graphviz_layout(G, prog='circo')
        nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)

    return nx.average_clustering(G)

total_coefficient = 0
for i in range(1,100000):
    coefficient  = getClusteringCoefficient(12)
    total_coefficient = total_coefficient+ coefficient
    
print(total_coefficient/i)
```

Comment: from the first graph to the second there seems to be a bigger transformation than simply adding more links. Perhaps this is adding more links after some rewiring on a Watts-Strogatz graph? Could you provide the code to replicate these averages?

Comment: @torresmateo I have added the code to the end of question

Comment: @torresmateo yes it is Watts-Strogatz graph

Comment: Ok, as I understand it, you start with the regular Watts-Strogatz, you don't rewire the graph, and then you add N/2 edges. Just so I understand the question, what is the average clustering coefficient you were expecting?

Comment: @torresmateo I need the formula to calculate average clustering coefficient

Comment: The formula you posted is correct. You can see that it is the same they use in `networkx` from their documentation for [`clustering`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cluster.clustering.html#networkx.algorithms.cluster.clustering) and [`average_clustering`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cluster.average_clustering.html#networkx.algorithms.cluster.average_clustering). The latter is simply defined as the average of the first one.

Comment: As I understood, the formula which I posted is for the lattice network. I need the formula for the graph with random links

Comment: The formula is the same for any graph. For the lattice, it will simply give 0.5 in every case (because of the regularity of the lattice itself). When adding links, the formula stays the same, but the results will change. Depending on the size of `N`, the expected value of the clustering coefficient will change according to the number of possible configurations.